# Rails - Find Total Number of Points for all users with Gem Merit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, merit-gem

I'm using the [Merit Gem](https://github.com/tute/merit) and am trying to find the total number of points achieved on my site.

To find each user's point count it's as easy as this

```
user.points
```

This shows the integer for that user's points. What I'm trying to find is find the total amount of points earned by all users. I'm not familiar with how to achieve this. I've looked into http://api.rubyonrails.org/ to try and solve it myself but haven't been successful.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: I don't know merit, but do you have a model called `Point` or `Score`? If so you could maybe do `Point.all` or `Score.all` to get all score records in your database.

Comment: Actually the way the gem finds that is different and I just figured it out! it's `Merit::Score::Point.sum("num_points")` Thank you for the reply @cantonic

Comment: Glad you found it out :)